# How to have a recursive droppable function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My Code:

```js
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").
        find("p").
        html("Dropped!");
    }
});
```

This was just a dummy to check whether my droppable function is working or not. It is working, but only once. I need it to be recursive so that I can drag  and drop elements on it as many times as I want.

Comment: need to explain what you mean by `recursive` in more detail. Really unclear what you are asking. Provide a demo

Comment: Do you mean you want the child elements of `#droppable` to also be droppable?

Comment: I don't think "recursive" is the word you're looking for.

Comment: `recursive` !== `reusable`

Answer (score 0):

It might by happening
just make the indication like this

```
$(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight").find("p").html("Dropped!")
    .delay(1000).html('').removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
```